# Scroll issue with LazyColumn inside BottomSheetDialogFragment

Tags: android, scroll, android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet, lazycolumn

I use `LazyColumn` inside `BottomSheetDialogFragment`, but if to scroll `LazyColumn` list UP then `Bottom` Sheet Dialog scrolls instead of `LazyColumn` list. Seems like `BottomSheetDialogFragment` intercepts user touch input.

That's how it looks:

[image]

How to properly use `LazyColumn` inside `BottomSheetDialogFragment`?

**MyBottomSheetDialogFragment.kt:**

```
class MyBottomSheetDialogFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
            setContent {
                Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
                    Text("Header", color = Color.Black)
                    LazyColumn(
                        Modifier
                            .weight(1f)
                            .fillMaxWidth()) {
                        items(100) {
                            Text("Item $it", Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), Color.Black)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And show it using this code:

```
MyBottomSheetDialogFragment().show(activity.supportFragmentManager, null)
```

When we used the XML `RecyclerView` list, to fix this issue we had to wrap the `RecyclerView` list with `NestedScrollView` like [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54777104/14455214), but how to fix it with Jetpack Compose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an excellent answer to this issue. We can use Jetpack Compose bottom sheet over Android view using Kotlin extension.

More details about how it works are [here](https://proandroiddev.com/jetpack-compose-bottom-sheet-over-android-view-using-kotlin-extension-7fecfa8fe369).

Here is all code we need:

```
// Extension for Activity
fun Activity.showAsBottomSheet(content: @Composable (() -> Unit) -> Unit) {
    val viewGroup = this.findViewById(android.R.id.content) as ViewGroup
    addContentToView(viewGroup, content)
}

// Extension for Fragment
fun Fragment.showAsBottomSheet(content: @Composable (() -> Unit) -> Unit) {
    val viewGroup = requireActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content) as ViewGroup
    addContentToView(viewGroup, content)
}

// Helper method
private fun addContentToView(
    viewGroup: ViewGroup,
    content: @Composable (() -> Unit) -> Unit
) {
    viewGroup.addView(
        ComposeView(viewGroup.context).apply {
            setContent {
                BottomSheetWrapper(viewGroup, this, content)
            }
        }
    )
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
private fun BottomSheetWrapper(
    parent: ViewGroup,
    composeView: ComposeView,
    content: @Composable (() -> Unit) -> Unit
) {
    val TAG = parent::class.java.simpleName
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val modalBottomSheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden)
    var isSheetOpened by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    ModalBottomSheetLayout(
        sheetBackgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
        sheetState = modalBottomSheetState,
        sheetContent = {
            content {
                // Action passed for clicking close button in the content
                coroutineScope.launch {
                    modalBottomSheetState.hide() // will trigger the LaunchedEffect
                }
            }
        }
    ) {}

    BackHandler {
        coroutineScope.launch {
            modalBottomSheetState.hide() // will trigger the LaunchedEffect
        }
    }

    // Take action based on hidden state
    LaunchedEffect(modalBottomSheetState.currentValue) {
        when (modalBottomSheetState.currentValue) {
            ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden -> {
                when {
                    isSheetOpened -> parent.removeView(composeView)
                    else -> {
                        isSheetOpened = true
                        modalBottomSheetState.show()
                    }
                }
            }
            else -> {
                Log.i(TAG, "Bottom sheet ${modalBottomSheetState.currentValue} state")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 28):

Since compose `1.2.0-beta01` problem can be solved by using
[rememberNestedScrollInteropConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/platform/package-summary#rememberNestedScrollInteropConnection()):

```kotlin
Modifier.nestedScroll(rememberNestedScrollInteropConnection())
```

In my case `BottomSheetDialogFragment` is standard `View` and it has `ComposeView` with id `container`. In `onViewCreated` I do:

```kotlin
binding.container.setContent {
    AppTheme {
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier.nestedScroll(rememberNestedScrollInteropConnection())
        ) {
            LazyColumn {
                // ITEMS
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And now the list is scrolling in a correct way.

Comment: I have a problem with the top of the bottomsheet not responding when i try to drag downwards to close the bottomsheet, is this the expected behaviour? (I have a Text-composable above the LazyColumn)

Comment: @Tob237 Did you manage to resolve the downwards dragging issue? I am facing the same behavior where the top of the sheet is not responding to drag events.

Comment: I faced with the same issue guys @MarcelSchnelle. Asked about it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75478019/the-title-wont-minimize-dialog-in-jetpack-compose-bottomsheetdialog-with-rememb

Comment: For me the top dragging issue can be fixed by adding `modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())` to the header/title/top composable. Documentation also mentions: "To resolve this, make sure you also set scrollable modifiers to these types of nested composables"

Comment: The fix from @EdwardvanRaak helps to solve this issue since the scrolling deltas from the "not Scrolling" elements has also be passed to the NestedScrollConnection provided by rememberNestedScrollInteropConnection.
You may ran into a render error `Vertically scrollable component was measured with an infinity maximum height...` To solve this you may add a hight to those "parent" elements by e.g. using `Modifier.height(intrinsicSize = IntrinsicSize.Max)`

Answer (score 4):

You might give a try to this https://gist.github.com/chrisbanes/053189c31302269656c1979edf418310.

> This is a workaround for https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/174348612, which means that nested scrolling layouts in Compose do not work as nested scrolling children in the view system.

Sample usage in your case :

```kotlin
class MyBottomSheetDialogFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
            setContent {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.nestedScroll(rememberViewInteropNestedScrollConnection())
                ){
                    LazyColumn(
                        Modifier
                            .weight(1f)
                            .fillMaxWidth()) {
                        items(100) {
                            Text("Item $it", Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), Color.Black)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you’re using compose within the activity that launched the bottom sheet dialog fragment, you might be better off simply sticking with a purely compose implementation and leveraging the compose equivalent bottom sheet component: ModalBottomSheetLayout

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#ModalBottomSheetLayout(kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.material.ModalBottomSheetState,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,kotlin.Function0)

Comment: I would like to use `ModalBottomSheetLayout`, but so far architecture of the application doesn't allow do implement this easily to the needed place. Seems like a lot of refactoring will be needed. That's why I use `BottomSheetDialogFragment`. Also, I use `Jetpack Compose` since new screens in the application we decided to write with this new technology. Anyway, thank you for the answer!