# Jetpack compose Bottom sheet is getting Collapsed with swipe inside its content

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet

I have a lazy column inside the bottom sheet. When I scroll the column up the sheet is also getting collapsed with it. I have tried setting sheetGesturesEnabled to false but it does not work in my case. Here is a code snippet.

```
    @OptIn(ExperimentalAnimationApi::class, ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
    @Composable
    fun SheetContent() {
        Box(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .heightIn(min = screenHeight, max = screenHeight)
                
        ) {
                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(rowHeight)
                ) {

                    LazyColumn() {
                        ...
                    }

                    LazyColumn() {
                        ...
                    }

                    LazyColumn() {
                        ...
                    }
                    
                }
            }

        }
```

Adding Bottom sheet implementation here. I am guessing the problem must be with nested items i.e. lazy columns inside the sheet content.

```
    @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
    @Composable
    fun BottomsheetScreen() {
     val bottomSheetScaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState(
                bottomSheetState = BottomSheetState(BottomSheetValue.Collapsed)
            )
            val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    
            BottomSheetScaffold(
                scaffoldState = bottomSheetScaffoldState,
                sheetShape = RoundedCornerShape(32.dp, 32.dp),
                sheetElevation = 8.dp,
                sheetContent = {
                    SheetContent()
                },
                sheetPeekHeight = 0.dp,
                sheetGesturesEnabled = false,
                drawerGesturesEnabled = false
            ) {
                Button(onClick = {
                    coroutineScope.launch {
                        if (bottomSheetScaffoldState.bottomSheetState.isCollapsed) {
                            bottomSheetScaffoldState.bottomSheetState.expand()
                        } else {
                            bottomSheetScaffoldState.bottomSheetState.collapse()
                        }
                    }
                }) {
                    Text(text = "Expand/Collapse Bottom Sheet")
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: Try turning on nested scrolling in UI

Comment: What is the expected user interaction to close the bottom sheet?

Comment: @KaranMehta I tried it didn't work. Is there some way to disable the bottom sheet drag?

Comment: @Abhimanyu There is a button to submit the data and close the bottom sheet.

Comment: @MARSK my requirement is that I need three lazy columns and all three have a different state. Also, can you clarify what you mean by thinking in compose in this case? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you share the bottom sheet logic as well, please? It's not feasible to solve your issue without looking at its implementation.

Comment: @MARSK added the sheet implementation code.

Comment: I had the exact same issue, and using https://stackoverflow.com/a/70835975/10276942, solved the problem for me.